# Single instance for 2 activity by Dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I wonder if I'm doing it in a good way.
If I want one instance `CoffeHelper` in `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`,
I make:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static CoffeeComponent getCoffeeComponent() {
        return coffeeComponent;
    }

    private static CoffeeComponent coffeeComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        coffeeComponent = createCoffeeComponent();
    }

    private CoffeeComponent createCoffeeComponent() {
        return DaggerCoffeeComponent.builder().build();
    }
}
```

--

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CoffeeProvider.class})
public interface CoffeeComponent {

    void provideCoffe(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void provideCoffe(SecondActivity secondActivity);

}
```

and now I can just write into MainActivity and into SecondActivity do this:

```
MyApplication.getCoffeeComponent().provideCoffe(this);
```

it is good practice ?

my module:

```
@Module
public class CoffeeProvider {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    CoffeeHelper getCoffeeHelper(){
        return new CoffeeHelper();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, show the insides of `CoffeeProvider` `@Module`-annotated class

Comment: Ok, done, check pls

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: ok, sorry, I was drunk, lets revert my post

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the only instance of `CoffeeHelper` will be provided into both `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`, assuming they have declaration as such: `@Inject CoffeeHelper helper`. The only instance will be returned due to [scoping](https://www.techyourchance.com/dagger-2-scopes-demystified/), whereas `@Singleton` is a dagger-2 scoping annotation.

> Is it a good practice?

It is quite questionable and mostly opinion-based, but it is very common pattern unless you use dagger modules designed for android usage (which provides `AndroidInjector` and other conveniences).